# Is there a way to set automatic data deletion in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, browser, bookmarks

Is there a way to set over the *ini* file so that after 10 minutes the page data in the inactive bookmarks are deleted?

In the bookmark would be only the URL information page. When an inactive bookmark is opened, the page will be reloaded. If the bookmark is not active for more than 10 minutes again, the page data is deleted.

And after opening the browser, bookmarks were not loaded before they opened.

The goal is save RAM even when opening multiple bookmarks. I think that was previously set in old versions of Firefox.

Comment: @bertieb : Is it readable? I work with google translator. If a sentence did not make sense, you can fix it. I just tried the editor options. I thought it was to be used. But obviously only at first occurrence. On long queries do not see tags because they are at the end.

Comment: I removed the in-text tags to make it more readable. The tags can help people *find* the question, but not *answer* it, so they belong at the end :)